# VBA Inputbox Filter enhancements

Tags: vba, excel

the code below works fine. However, when a user doesn't include anything in the InputBox **or** clicks on the 'Close' button **or** inputs a value which doesn't exist I want it to display a msgbox stating the reason and delete sheets 'PreTotal'.

Is there a better way to handle user input? Need some help here on how to go about it. Thank you.

```
Sub Filterme()
    Dim wSheetStart As Worksheet
    Dim rFilterHeads As Range
    Dim strCriteria As String

    Set wSheetStart = ActiveSheet
    Set rFilterHeads = Range("M1", Range("M1").End(xlToLeft))

    With wSheetStart
        .AutoFilterMode = False

        rFilterHeads.AutoFilter

        strCriteria = InputBox("Enter Date - MMDDYY")

        If strCriteria = vbNullString Then Exit Sub

        rFilterHeads.AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="=*" & strCriteria & "*"
    End With

    Worksheets("PreTotal").UsedRange.Copy

    Sheets.Add.Name = "Total"

    Worksheets("Total").Range("A1").PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

Change

```
If strCriteria = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
```

to

```
If strCriteria = vbNullString Then
    MsgBox "You choose not to continue"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Worksheets("PreTotal").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Exit Sub
End If
```

**FOLLOWUP**

> > > Thanks @Rout - This worked. One more thing what if the input criteria does not exist in the sheet? How should I tackle that? – user823911 11 mins ago

Is this what you are trying? Also if you are filtering the range based on **Col M** (1st Col in the range) then change the line

```
rFilterHeads.AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="=*" & strCriteria & "*"
```

to

```
rFilterHeads.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*" & strCriteria & "*"
```

**CODE**

```
Sub Filterme()
    Dim wSheetStart As Worksheet
    Dim rFilterHeads As Range, aCell As Range
    Dim strCriteria As String

    Set wSheetStart = ActiveSheet
    Set rFilterHeads = Range("M1", Range("M1").End(xlToLeft))

    With wSheetStart
        .AutoFilterMode = False

        strCriteria = InputBox("Enter Date - MMDDYY")

        If strCriteria = vbNullString Then
            MsgBox "You choose not to continue"
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            Worksheets("PreTotal").Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Set aCell = .Columns(13).Find(What:=strCriteria, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Search Criteria Not Found"
            Exit Sub
        End If

        rFilterHeads.AutoFilter

        rFilterHeads.AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="=*" & strCriteria & "*"

        Sheets.Add.Name = "Total"
        Worksheets("PreTotal").UsedRange.Copy
        Worksheets("Total").Range("A1").PasteSpecial
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @Rout - This worked. One more thing what if the input criteria does not exist in the sheet? How should I tackle that?